# Помогите решить задачу проверки угрозы королю на шахматной доске

Tags: python, шахматы

> На шахматной доске находятся король и несколько ферзей другого цвета.
> Проверить находится ли король под угрозой и если да, кто ему угрожает.
> Положение фигур задано массивом K(8,8): 0-клетка пуста, 1-король,
> 2-ферзь. Ферзь бьет по горизонтали, вертикали, диагонали

Спустя какое-то время было много вариантов как это сделать и в итоге ни один не сработал.

В конечном результате получил это, но понял, что нужно описывать ход ферзя, а не позицию, но не знаю как. Еще был вариант через матрицы, но я с ними не особо хорошо лажу)

пробовал создавать кортежи, списки, но...

```
king_x = (input("x: "))
king_y = (input("y: "))
queen1_x = (input("x: "))
queen1_y = (input("y: "))
queen2_x = (input("x: "))
queen2_y = (input("y: "))

if king_x == queen1_x and king_y == queen1_y:
    print("First queen take damage for king")
else:
    print("loxushka")
if king_x == queen2_x and king_y == queen2_y:
    print("Second queen take damage for king")
else:
    print("loxushka")
```

Comment: проверьте, есть ли на вертикалях, горизонталях и диагоналях (от позиции короля) ферзи, это и будет ответом на "находится ли король под угрозой"

Comment: оригинальный способ у вас называть ферзей ))

Comment: Если бы я знал, как проверить на вертикалях, горизонталях, диагоналях)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм следующий: Задаем расположение короля, ферзей. Потом проверяем, находится ли король на общих вертикалях, горизонталях, диагоналях с ферзями. Если король под ударом, то выведутся координаты ферзей которые это делают.

Примерно так:

```py
def point():
    return int(input("x: ")), int(input("y: "))

print("King")
king = point()

queens = []
for i in range(1,3):
    print("Queen" + str(i))
    queens.append(point())

*res, = filter(lambda p: p[0] == king[0], queens) # вертикаль
print(res)

*res, = filter(lambda p: p[1] == king[1], queens) # горизонталь
print(res)

*res, = filter(lambda p: (p[1] - p[0]) == (king[1] - king[0]), queens) # диагональ 1
print(res)

*res, = filter(lambda p: (king[0] + king[1]) == (p[0] + p[1]), queens) # диагональ 2
print(res)
```

Для [3D-шахмат](https://www.chessvariants.com/3d.dir/3d5.html) будет немного отличаться.

Comment: А можно объяснить как здесь все работает?

Comment: @ИгорьСмирнов, все также как у вас, задаем расположение короля, ферзей. Потом проверяем, находится ли король на общих вертикалях, горизонталях, диагоналях с ферзями. Если король под ударом, то выведутся координаты ферзей которые это делают.

Comment: Честно, не понимаю как работают *res и lambda)

Comment: по ламбде - это анонимная функция(нет имени), в данном случае используется для фильтрования списка ферзей(queens) если условие выполняется то ферзь добавляется в новый отфильтрованный список, p - это точка где находится ферзь. `*res, = filter(...)` - это тоже самое что и `res = list(filter(...))`

Comment: Понял, спасибо огромное!